# Cannot add service reference: the content type text/html [..] does not match the content type of the binding

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, soap

I have a Web API and i want to call an online web service that uses SOAP.

I tried to add it as "service reference" however when I call it am getting the below summarized error

> The content type text/html of the response message does not match the
>    content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a 
>    custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method
>    is implemented properly. The first 13 bytes of the response were: `<HTML></HTML>`

The binding in my `web.config` is `basicHttpBinding` and I checked if the binding configuration matched the WSDL configuration and it does.

This is the URL am trying to consume:
http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl

Is it possible to consume SOAP from Web API ?

Comment: Open the URL in your browser and check what's on the page. You get a web page (`text/html`) where you'd expect a WSDL (`text/xml`).

Comment: I agree with @CodeCaster: The service seems to response with a weg-page - this is maybe an error page => show the whole response somehow.

Comment: thank you for your comments, i added the info your required.

Comment: The WebAPI part is irrelevant, you're trying to create a WCF proxy which is possible in pretty much any type of application, regardless of other libraries used in that application. The error you get means you made a mistake while pasting the URL. Does the URL work in the browser? Does your company's proxy server block the request?

Comment: I tried it from a normal asp project and its working fine. Yes it does work

Comment: I found something weird, when i test a positive scenario it works without any problem, however when i test a negative scenario it crashes with the above error.

Comment: What is "a negative scenario"?

Comment: Add try-catch statements.

Comment: yeah that's what i did :) thanks a lot for your help! Weird tho that its crashing the system with that odd message

Answer (score 0):

I though I had some experience with the service VIES. I can confirm that you can consume SOAP service with C# .NET. I posted the solution on my [blog](http://www.dontesta.it/blog/programming/vies-check-vat/) and find on GitHub repository [VIESCheckVatService](https://github.com/amusarra/VIESCheckVatService) the whole project.

I hope you can help.